# Unity what are the rules for determining sizes of gameobjects

Tags: unity

I am making a game for windows phone. I am a newbie so currently I am unable to understand if I have to make a simple menu for a game targeting portrait mode always, what should I give the background size ,camera size ,button size , position? For example I have to set a background on renderer  full screen size in portrait mode and fis a gui test between it.. I am using 2d orthographic camera

Comment: Scroll down to the point where it talks about sizing the background sprite to fit into your viewport http://www.raywenderlich.com/61532/unity-2d-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you design a UI according to a fixed screen size like (480X800 WP) then use GUI.matrix (see the script reference) to scale it to different resolutions.

GUI.matrix is really useful but a very heavy function. so make sure you use less OnGUI objects like buttons, boxes, and textures.

A better way to implement textures is using Quads. Quads are rendered by the camera and the Camera Scale is taken care by unity.